# How to use both service-to-service AND Cognito auth for API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have a RESTful API being accessed via AWS API Gateway. I want both human users (authenticated via Cognito) *AND* other (internal) services to be able to call the API. There exists plenty of documentation of how to do either, but not for how to do *both*.

I have tried using unauthenticated Cognito federated identities to authorize *services*. I have also used Cognito user pools to authenticate *people*. However, API Gateway only allows for a single authorizer (in this case, either AWS_IAM *or* a Cognito authorizer). However, I don't see a way to do both.

I imagine I will need a custom Lambda authorizer, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding accurate information on how to write an authorizer using IAM *or* Cognito.

Surely we can't be the first people to want to allow both services and humans access to an API. The dearth of documentation on doing so leads me to believe I'm either missing something painfully obvious or that this is a use case that is best avoided (in which case, what IS best practice?).

Is there any way of doing both? Is there a Lambda authorizer example that can point me in the right direction? Is there something built-in that I'm missing?

We have rejected the idea of "pretending" that a Cognito user is a human, when in fact it's actually a service, as it seems to us to be a misuse of Cognito user pools and identity federation. Likewise, the opposite, where a Cognito user is federated to act as an IAM role shared by both users and services, seems like a misuse of user authentication.

Is there a canonical way to do this? If not, is there existing documentation of how to write a custom Lambda authorizer to do both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: you (probably) don't need to use API Gateway for either case.

API Gateway, as the name suggests, is just a gateway. It takes a request (often HTTP) and forwards it to another location (a Lambda function, an EC2 instance, another AWS service, or another HTTP endpoint). This is great if you need users *who do not have an associated IAM role* to access AWS services.

Users who are authenticated through Cognito have an associated IAM role through the associated Cognito Identity Pool. Just give them access to the AWS services this way, no need to go through API Gateway.

AWS services that need access to other AWS services don't need to go through API Gateway, they need to be given permission through their IAM role.

If for some reason you must use API Gateway for both your users and your services, make two API Gateways that point to the same resources that use different authentication methods.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We do need to use API gateway in order to achieve a RESTful-like interface while the underlying API is deployed via Lambda (using the `serverless` framework).  We have a SPA UI that invokes the Lambda functions as though they are RESTful, so that we can abstract the actual lambda invocations in case we want to change architecture later. (I didn't include this info because it's not quite relevant to my question.)

I was trying to avoid two gateway instances, because that also means double the maintenance for the same function(s), but maybe that is the "right" way.

Comment: You don't need API Gateway to have a RESTful interface. Using the AWS SDK on the frontend, you just directly call the InvokeFunction method to invoke your Lambda function. This is the most popular use case and handles Cognito authentication seamlessly.

Comment: The actual application is written using Python's flask framework, which is being deployed as a Lambda function, and made RESTful by API Gateway. We want to use that so that we can also test locally, and if desired, change to a classic server architecture. Using API Gateway, the front end doesn't have to change if we wind up changing how the backend is deployed. Unless there's something I'm missing here?

Comment: Alright, if you are looking to change the backend architecture and want to make zero changes to the frontend, API Gateway is the right choice. But I want to point out that API Gateway is not what makes your serverless architecture RESTful, Lambda is already RESTful and API Gateway is just forwarding your requests to the function. One of the great benefits of using Cognito and Lambda is that you don't have to worry about this and authentication is handled completely through IAM.

Comment: That last sentence is what I'm not sure about. Cognito doesn't allow me to access the standard IAM credentials (the access key id, and the secret access key) that is so often used for IAM authentication. Getting those credentials requires an `IdentityId`, and I haven't found any way to obtain that from an authenticated Cognito user, only the `id_token`, which is not the same. 

That said, the more I think about it, your suggestion of two gateways for the same function is probably the least hassle (with the least amount of maintenace) for what we're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Access Key ID and Secret Access Key are used for IAM Users, but not Roles. When you set up a Cognito Identity Pool, you give it an IAM role that authenticated users can assume, no access key id or secret needed, just an access token (different than ID token). Then, from the frontend, a user has whatever permissions that the IAM role has and can access the allowed resources (in this case, access to InvokeFunction).

Comment: Yes. That much I have, and have set up, but using API Gateway, this is still an either/or situation. So, based on your original suggestion, if the front end doesn't call `/some/endpoint` but instead uses a call to Invoke function, we do not need either dual auth (i.e., we'd only have to use only policies to gate invocation) nor API gateway? (Just being explicit so that my team can discuss which approach we like better.)

Comment: Correct. In the JavaScript SDK this is as simple as setting `AWS.config.credentials` to a new `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` with the provided access token. More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html).

Comment: Great. Thank you for the great detail!